# Web Api 2: [Required] for value types?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-4.5

Using the `[Required]` data annotation in Web Api input models only seems to check for reference types being instantiated to null:

```
public class MyInputModel
{
    [Required] // This works! ModelState fails.
    public CustomClass MyCustomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

How can we get this to work with value types WITHOUT the default instantiation?

```
public class MyInputModel
{
    [Required] // This is ignored because MyDouble is defaulted to 0
    public double MyDouble { get; set; }
}
```

Is the only way through using `Nullable<Double>`? Could we not create some custom validation attribute?

Comment: You can always write custom validation attribute. E.g http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260177/Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the required attribute working internally.

```
 override bool IsValid(object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return false;
        }

        // only check string length if empty strings are not allowed
        var stringValue = value as string;
        if (stringValue != null && !AllowEmptyStrings) {
            return stringValue.Trim().Length != 0;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

So nothing to do with the 0 value so you must check it with Range attribute

Answer (score 4):

you can use the range attribute.

```
[Range(0, 99)]
public double MyDouble { get; set; }
```

Comment: Except that in my case, a value of 0 isn't the same as no value. 0 is still valid.

Answer (score 3):

try making value type Nullable e.g. `public double? MyDouble { get; set; }`