# Possible to enforce [Required] on value types

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, deserialization, data-annotations, c#-6.0

If you put [Required] on a reference type, and provide JSON without a matching JSON attribute, an error is thrown.

Aside from using nullable value types, or wrapping value types in classes, is it possible to enforce [Required] on a value type when deserializing a request to Web API?

Required doesn't get enforced on Test1 below because it is coerced to the default value of zero. I.e., if your JSON doesn't include a Field1 property, serialization still completes successfully.

I'd like to be able to put [Required] on my value type or possibly write a new attribute to accomplish this.

Is there a setting to do this? Or, is it possible to tap into the deserialization for both XML and JSON to achieve this?

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Method1(Clas1 model){}

public class Class1
{
    ...

    [Required]
    public int Field1 { get; set; }
}
```

[Although it may not be possible with attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947065/web-api-2-required-for-value-types), theoretically the deserializer could check for the attribute before coercing the value to the value type. If so, are there events or settings in which I can do that?

With Json.net, I can add an attribute [ JsonProperty(Required = Required.AllowNull)]. Is there something similar I can do for XML deserialization?

Ie:

```
// POST api/Account/Register
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

public class RegisterBindingModel  //: IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int Test1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Test3 { get; set; }

<RegisterBindingModel xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApplication1.Models">
  <Email>Sample string 2</Email>
  <Test1>2</Test1>
</RegisterBindingModel>
```

Comment: Won't it always have a value?  When you instantiate that class, `Field1` will have a value of 0 if it is not explicitly set to some other value.

Comment: Yes it will. But I want to invalidate the ModelState and reject the request if Field1 is not explicitly provided

Comment: *Aside from using nullable value types* - Why have you discounted this approach?

Comment: I have a large API, and don't want to go through and change all of the primitives to nullable types. Difficult to verify that I won't impact business requirements

Comment: Change to nullable or use Range, I prefer to use Range. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662976/required-attribute-for-an-integer-value

Comment: You can do achieve what you want with: https://thom.ee/blog/clean-way-to-bind-required-value-types-in-asp-net-core/ Works without ranges, all value types not just ints, no nullable needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the range, you can use the range attribute.

```
[Range(0, 99)]
public int Field1{ get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm looking for something more robust. I want to force the request to explicitly provide the attribute

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that I found is to make that property optional, and then, in a validation, check for not-null.